# mvvmcross sqlite-PCL iOS security

Tags: ios, sqlite, security, plugins, mvvmcross

Hi I have been using the MVVMCross-SQLite plugin [link](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-SQLite). Using this I could use the SQLiteOpenFlags to enable the database to use the iOS platform security option of ProtectionComplete.

This plugin has been deprecated, so I want to upgrade to the SQLite-PCL plugin. However I cannot see a way to set an iOS security option with this plugin. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry I did not realise that this used SQLite.NET as well, which means I can overwrite the factory class to change the SQLiteOpenFlags. Ive answered my own question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I did not realise that this used SQLite.NET as well, which means I can overwrite the factory class to change the SQLiteOpenFlags. Ive answered my own question